# How to implement a batch process functionality in nodejs where output on first function will be input to next function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async-await

Consider we have array with functions (normal and promise functions)

```
var arrCallback = [fun1(),promiseFunc2(),fun3(),...];
```

each function will return a value which must be sent as input to next function sequentially .

Example :

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

main(1); // This works
main(2); // Fails ; Expected output ==> {z: 1} {a: 1} {c: 1}

/*
 * Complete the function below.
 */`enter code here`
function Process() {
    // Write your code here.
    var arrCallback = [];
    var run = function (data) {
      global.data = data;
      arrCallback.map(cb => execteFunction(data,cb));
    };

    var execteFunction = (data,cb) => global.data = cb(global.data); 

    var next = function(fn){ 
        arrCallback.push(fn);
    }

    var onError = function(fn){
        arrCallback.push(fn);
    }

    return{
        run: run,
        next : next,
        onError: onError
    }
 }

function main(test) {
    console.log("tets:",test);

    if (test === 1) return test1()
    if (test === 2) return test2()
    if (test === 3) return test3()

    function test1 () {
        const process = new Process()
        process.next((val) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(val) + '\n')
          return { a: 1 }
        })
        process.next((val) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(val) + '\n')
          return { b: 1 }
        })
        process.run({ z: 1 })
    }

    function test2 () {
        const process = new Process()
        process.next((val) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(val) + '\n')
          return { a: 1 }
        })
        process.next((val) => new Promise(resolve => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(val) + '\n')
          setTimeout(() => resolve({ c: 1 }), 1000)
        }))
        process.next((val) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(val) + '\n')
          return { b: 1 }
        })
        process.run({ z: 1 })
    }
}
```

The issue is in `test2()` method within `main()` has second function returning a promise .

Comment: Remember that asynchronous code is viral.  Any code that touches it also needs to be async-aware.  If you have a pipeline of functions for which any one of them might be async (like your `Promise`-returning one) then your infrastructure needs to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle that asynchronicity properly, you will need to change your `run` function.  Something like this might do:

```
var run = function(data) {
  return arrCallback.reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve(data))
}
```

The only other thing that would be required is to return the result out of your test functions:

```
return process.run({ z: 1 })
```

These functions will now return promises to which you can attach a callback via `.then`:

```
test2().then(console.log)
// logs:
// {"z":1}
// {"a":1}
// {"c":1}
// {"b":1}
```

But now that you have this, you might find it easier to avoid your whole `next` paradigm, and simply pass an array of functions to create a `Process`.  That's up to you, of course, but I think it's a simpler API.